# How to implement Resource Owner Password Credentals (ROPC) auth flow in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly, openiddict

I'd like my Blazor WebAssembly app to authenticate against an OpenID Connect (OIDC) server. The users should enter their username and password directly in the Blazor WebAssembly app rather than redirected to the server for authentication. Authenticated users should be granted a JWT for further communication.

Can someone provide a tutorial on how to implement this flow properly?

The Blazor WebAssembly app is hosted with ASP.NET Core, which has an [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) authorization server.

Comment: Hi @Draex_, I think you can check [this document](https://www.prowaretech.com/articles/current/blazor/wasm/jwt-authentication-simple).